# jQuery load method charset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the .load() method in jQuery but I've realized that the request to my server should use ISO-8859-1 charset and not UTF-8. The problem is that I can't find how to set load method to use a different encoding. I read that .ajax method has 'content-type' setting to do this, but what about load method? I find load very useful when I need to update data from some divs without refreshing the page.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What about using `ajaxSetup` as shown there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/330398/1063730

Comment: `.load` is just a shorthand method for `.ajax`. If you need more complex functionality than `.load` provides, use `.ajax`

Comment: @yoshi is right on the money, you simply use $.ajaxSetup and set it there.

Comment: Thanks @yoshi why don't you mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) allows you to specify the settings for new ajax calls.

> All subsequent Ajax calls using any function will use the new
>   settings, unless overridden by the individual calls, until the next
>   invocation of $.ajaxSetup().

with `beforeSend` you can provide a callback function to modify the XMLHttpRequest object before it's going to be send. [*jQuery Reference*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XMLHttpRequest#overrideMimeType) provides documentation about `overrideMimeType()`:

> Overrides the MIME type returned by the server. This may be used, for
>   example, to force a stream to be treated and parsed as text/xml, even
>   if the server does not report it as such.This method must be called
>   before send().

Borrowing code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/330398/1063730) you could do:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//$('body').append('<div id=qqq>dfsdfsdf</div>')
//$('#qqq').load2('/index.php?showtopic=925 #post-29397','','','text/html; charset=utf-8')
//$('#qqq').load2('/index.php?showtopic=925 #post-29397','','','text/plain; charset=windows-1251')
//


jQuery.fn.load2 = function( url, params, callback, overrideMimeTypeVar) {
    if ( typeof url !== "string" && _load ) {
        return _load.apply( this, arguments );
    }

    var selector, type, response,
        self = this,
        off = url.indexOf(" ");

    if ( off >= 0 ) {
        selector = jQuery.trim( url.slice( off ) );
        url = url.slice( 0, off );
    }

    // If it's a function
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( params ) ) {

        // We assume that it's the callback
        callback = params;
        params = undefined;

    // Otherwise, build a param string
    } else if ( params && typeof params === "object" ) {
        type = "POST";
    }

    // If we have elements to modify, make the request
    if ( self.length > 0 ) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,

            // if "type" variable is undefined, then "GET" method will be used
            type: type,
            dataType: "html",
            data: params,
            // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            beforeSend: function(x) {
                if(x && x.overrideMimeType && overrideMimeTypeVar!=''){
                    x.overrideMimeType(overrideMimeTypeVar);
                    }}
            // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++      
        }).done(function( responseText ) {

            // Save response for use in complete callback
            response = arguments;

            self.html( selector ?

                // If a selector was specified, locate the right elements in a dummy div
                // Exclude scripts to avoid IE 'Permission Denied' errors
                jQuery("<div>").append( jQuery.parseHTML( responseText ) ).find( selector ) :

                // Otherwise use the full result
                responseText );

        }).complete( callback && function( jqXHR, status ) {
            self.each( callback, response || [ jqXHR.responseText, status, jqXHR ] );
        });
    }

    return this;
};
```

Comment: This code adds to the Jquery function load2, which is similar to the load. In the fourth parameter in this function to override the MimeType.