# Specials chars from csv to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I have a `.csv` file. I grab the file using `jQuery.get()`.

```
$.get("data.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data)
}, "text")
```

Later I want to save the file in an xml.

Now my problem is the datatype of my text.

What I have Å, ë, ö, etc.

What I output �, �, �, �

**How can I get the correct format of the text from a .csv file into javascript?**

### Edit

My meta charset is OK: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

But notice that I don't display the output of the csv file, I just add some more info and save it in an xml.

When I console.log the output I see these � chars. The same when I save it in the xml. But in my csv file I have the correct char.

### Edit 2

I just found [this awesome tool](http://www.adrianparr.com/?p=142). It is in AS3.

When I insert `Å ë ö` I need the output of `escape()`.

When I use javascript.escape() for `Å` I get weird chars like `%uFFFD` instead of `%C5` so I guess my script tries to escape `�` to `%uFFFD`

### Solution

Here the solution for people who have the same problem.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
    }
})

$.get("data.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data)
}, "text")
```

Comment: what is the charset used in the page

Comment: More importantly, what's the `Content-Type` header that's sent by the server?

Comment: you need to replace special characters  with ISO Latin-1 codes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need  to replace special characters with ISO Latin codes.
for more reference check this link: http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html

Comment: Your tip was nice, caused me to find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330331/jquery-get-charset-of-reply-when-no-header-is-set

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the page's header

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: I don't display the output, I just want to data. My charset in the file that loads this javascript I have `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the escape sequences in the string. For instance,The escape sequences in Javascript all begin with the backslash character, . This character lets the application processing the string know that what follows is a sequence of characters that need special handling.