# Weird characters html

Tags: php, html, character

Characters like é keep turning into a �.
I'm kind of clueless right now it should have to do anything with unicode.
I already put this in my head:

It doesn't do this for every page, for example my index.php is exactly the same as support.php but only for support.php the é changes with �.

My head looks like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>TITLE</title>

<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/half-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Check the encoding of `support.php` file. `<meta charset="utf-8">` means that it'll be rendered as a UTF-8 document, whether or not it actually is.

Comment: If you're using Notepad to save your files with, it defaults to ANSI. You need to save the file as UTF-8.

Comment: You should [html encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) characters like that

Comment: Thanks Fred & rain, you guys are great!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why non-ascii chars are displayed as weird symbols?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909114/why-non-ascii-chars-are-displayed-as-weird-symbols)

Comment: @Pino That link doesn't give a good (or detailed) explanation as to how to fix it. The only thing that seems relevant in there is [`this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909114/why-non-ascii-chars-are-displayed-as-weird-symbols#comment38702002_24909427), so you'd need to find a better link such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through - Even still, there could be a better page that exists on Stack, which stands to exist.

Comment: @MitchellAntes Should you later have more problems such as `headers already sent....` warning message, it could mean that the file was saved as UTF-8 **with** [**BOM (byte order mark)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). A BOM counts as "output" before header, therefore you'd need to save the file as UTF-8 **without** BOM. This can be done using [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or another code editor offering different file saving options.